# Defining a Template Member of a Template Class separately from the Declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<class A> struct Foo
{
    template<class B> static bool Bar();
};

template<class B> template<class A>  bool Foo<A>::Bar<B>()
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool b = Foo<int>::Bar<long>();
    b;
}
```

This results in a linker error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl Foo<int>::Bar<long>(void)" (??$Bar@J@?$Foo@H@@SA_NXZ) referenced in function main
```

I need to define this member function outside of the class template's declaration.  In other words, I cannot do this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
template<class A> struct Foo
{
    template<class B> static bool Bar()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool b = Foo<int>::Bar<long>();
    b;
}
```

What am I missing?  How can I define this member function template?  What's the needed syntax?

Note:  I am using MSVC 2008, in case that's relevant.

EDIT

The first thing I tried was to reverse the order of `template<class A>` and `template<class B>`:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<class A> struct Foo
{
    template<class B> static bool Bar();
};

template<class A> template<class B>  bool Foo<A>::Bar<B>()
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    bool b = Foo<int>::Bar<long>();
    b;
}
```

This resulted in a compiler error:

```
.\main.cpp(11) : error C2768: 'Foo<A>::Bar' : illegal use of explicit template arguments
```

On the closing brace of the definition for the `Bar` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the order of `template<class B> template<class A>`. The second one is "inner" and goes with the member declaration. See §14.5.2/1.

Also, as John points out, remove the parameter-list from `Bar<B>`.

```
// "outer" template: this parameter gets substituted to create "inner" template
template< class A >

// "inner" template stands alone after "outer" substitution
template< class B >

bool
// This will just be a class name after "outer" substitution.
      foo<A>
// This has usual function template syntax
             :: Bar() {
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried.  That resulted in a compiler error.  I'll edit the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
template<class A>
template<class B>
bool Foo<A>::Bar()
{
    return true;
}
```

The order in which you write the two `template` specifiers matters (the outer template comes first). Also, if you actually put `<B>` on the name of the function template, at least one compiler (GCC) thinks you're trying to partially specialize the function `Bar`, which is impossible.

Comment: Appears to work for me as well, but what happens to `B`?  This is so wierd!

Comment: I get it now.lets chalk this one up to friday! Fun fun fun fun